# Error on collision between Player and Enemy

Tags: debugging, game-maker, gml

I'm running into an error when I collide with an enemy. I'm not sure if it happens when I touch it or when I take damage from it. Heres the error message:

---

#

FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Eventobj_player
for object obj_damage:

Variable < unknown_object >.y(1, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_damage_CollisionEvent_1_1 (line 6) -     var dir = point_direction(creator.x, creator.y, other.x, other.y);

#

---

Heres the collision event for obj_damage with the obj_player:

```
if(other.id != creator) {
obj_player_stats.hp -= damage;

/// Knockback
var dir = point_direction(creator.x, creator.y, other.x, other.y);
var xforce = lengthdir_x(knockback, dir);
var yforce = lengthdir_y(knockback, dir);
with (other) {
    physics_apply_impulse(x, y, xforce, yforce);
}
}
```

---

Any help appreciated, I will provide extra code if necessary to fix. Thanks.

Comment: Possible that `creator` obect is not exists. So, when you try get `x` of `creator`, you have the error. Try change `if(other.id != creator) {` to `if other.id != creator and instance_exists(creator) {`

Comment: @Dmi7ry That is something I thought of but wouldn't that completely not run my attack damage if the creator doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on my own, had a typo in my enemy collision with player, i put damage_creator and not damage.creator . I completely missed that when I was debugging, well you learn from mistakes (I am a newbie). Thanks for the help anyways.